QGIS - Retrieve the most recent value from the child table
I have a layer with objects (1_objects) whose status is regularly updated following visits. The updates are listed in the "Statuts" field of a table called 2_Statuts_suivi. I have set up a parent-child relationship of type 1-n. All this works well.
What I would like is to be able to retrieve the most recent value of the "statuts" field of the 2_Statuts_suivi table and use it in a legend, a layout or in a field of the parent layer 1_objects.
To achieve this, I calculate a "rank" field in a virtual field of the table 2_Statuts_suivi with the expression:
array_find(
array_sort(
array_agg( "fid" ,
group_by:= "UUID_Objet" ,
order_by:="Date_creation desc"
), ascending:=false
),
"fid"
) +1

Then in a virtual field of the 1_objets layer I retrieve the value with the expression:
aggregate(
layer:='Statuts_suivi',
aggregate:= 'concatenate',
expression:="Statuts",

filter := "rank"=1 AND "UUID_Obs" = attribute(@parent, 'UUID'))

The 1_objets layer and the 2_Statut_suivi table are saved in the same geopackage.
It works, but it is very very slow.
Is there a more elegant solution to retrieve the most recent value from the child table?

You don't need 2 expressions if you use relation_aggregate where my_relation is the name of the 1:n relation definded in project properties, something like the following expression:
 array_last(relation_aggregate( 
            'my_relation',
            'array_agg'
            ,"Statuts_suivi",
             order_by:="Date_creation"))


Thanks for the answer! It is indeed more efficient. But it does not solve the slowness problems. Is it normal that several minutes of waiting are necessary to open the project or after saving the parent layer.

What type of layers do you have in your project? If there are a lot of (complex) virtual layers, it may be slow to open the project as they have to be evaluated when the project is opened. Or, some people experience slow loading times if their project, or data, are on a network drive.

@Matt I work with a geopackage and WMS basemaps. With the changes made, I only have one virtual field.
The geopackage and the QGis project are saved on my SSD hard drive.
The project and the updating of the entities is really slowed down as long as I use the virtual field.
